# XML ordering giving requires parent tags to be opened first error

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure

Below query is giving error related to XML ordering.

> Parent tag ID 10 is not among the open tags. `FOR XML EXPLICIT` requires parent tags to be opened first. Check the ordering of the result set

> Parent tag ID 2 is not among the open tags. `FOR XML EXPLICIT` requires parent tags to be opened first. Check the ordering of the result set.

I need help in understating why its giving intermittent errors. These error come intermittently and not always

```
    select 1         as Tag,                    
       null   as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                        
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
                null                                as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null     as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                       
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                         
     union ALL                    
                         
     -- Custom menu from list table                    
     select 2         as Tag,                    
       1         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       tsg.GroupCode      as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                    
       tsg.GroupName      as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                    
       coalesce(m.DisplayOrder,1)   as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                    
       1         as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                    
       1         as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       null        as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null        as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       null     as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                    
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                           
     from                    
       dbo.tbl_MenuGroup m                    
       INNER JOIN @TempScheduleGroups tsg                    
        ON m.GroupCode = tsg.GroupCode                     
     where                    
       m.COAID = @COAID                    
                         
     union ALL                    
                         
     -- Default group for non - TA Schedules                    
     select 2         as Tag,                    
       1         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       ScheduleCode      as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                    
       DisplayOrder      as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                    
       0         as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       null        as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null        as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                    
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                           
     from                    
       #TempSchedules                    
                           
     where               
       IsTA = 0                    
       AND ScheduleGroup IS NULL                    
                           
     union ALL                    
                         
     -- Schedules - non TA                      
     select 3         as Tag,                    
       2         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                      
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       coalesce(ts.ScheduleGroup,                     
        ts.ScheduleCode)    as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                       
       coalesce(tsg.GroupName, null)  as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                       
       coalesce(tsg.DisplayOrder, ts.DisplayOrder)                 
                as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                       
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                       
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                       
                           
       ts.ScheduleCode      as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       ts.BaseScheduleCode     as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       ts.ScheduleCode      as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       ScheduleName      as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       ts.DisplayOrder      as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       ts.IsMandatory       as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       ts.InUse        as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       ts.IsTracked      as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       ts.Status       as [Row!3!Status],                    
       coalesce(ts.ScheduleGroup, null) as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       ~IsTA        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       0         as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                    
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                       
                       
     from                     
      #TempSchedules ts                    
      LEFT OUTER JOIN @TempScheduleGroups tsg                     
       ON ts.ScheduleGroup = tsg.GroupCode                       
     where                     
      IsTA = 0                    
                         
     union ALL                    
                         
     -- Default standard menu from tMenu table for TA schedules                     
     select 2         as Tag,                    
       1         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       GroupCode       as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                      
       GroupName       as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],            DisplayOrder      as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                       
       Visible        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                       
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       null        as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null        as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],           
       0         as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                    
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                           
     from                                      
       @TempScheduleGroups                    
     where                    
       GroupCode IN (@CONST_SOURCE_GAPP_MENU_CODE, @CONST_DERIVED_GAPP_MENU_CODE)                    
                         
     union ALL                    
                         
     -- Schedules - TA                      
     select 3         as Tag,                    
       2         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                      
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       GroupCode       as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                       
       GroupName       as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                       
       g.DisplayOrder      as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                       
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                       
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                       
                           
       CASE                         
        WHEN GroupCode = @CONST_DERIVED_GAPP_MENU_CODE THEN ScheduleCode + '_S'                    
        ELSE ScheduleCode                    
       END         as [Row!3!RowID],                    
                s.BaseScheduleCode,                     
       CASE                         
        WHEN GroupCode = @CONST_DERIVED_GAPP_MENU_CODE THEN ScheduleCode + '_S'                    
        ELSE ScheduleCode     
       END         as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       ScheduleName      as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       s.DisplayOrder      as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       IsMandatory        as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       InUse         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       IsTracked        as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       Status        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       GroupCode       as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       ~IsTA        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       CASE                     
        WHEN GroupCode = @CONST_SOURCE_GAPP_MENU_CODE THEN 0                    
        WHEN GroupCode = @CONST_DERIVED_GAPP_MENU_CODE THEN 1                    
       END         as [Row!3!ReadOnly] ,                    
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                           
     from                     
      #TempSchedules s                    
      INNER JOIN @TempScheduleGroups g                    
       ON GroupCode IN (@CONST_SOURCE_GAPP_MENU_CODE, @CONST_DERIVED_GAPP_MENU_CODE)                      
     where                     
      IsTA = 1                    
                                   
     -- Applicable groups                    
     UNION ALL                    
                         
     select 10         as Tag,                    
       1         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       null        as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null        as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                       
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       0         as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]                    
                         
                         
     UNION ALL                    
                         
     select 11         as Tag,                    
       10         as Parent,                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroups!1],                    
       @HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess as [ScheduleGroups!1!HasScheduleTrackingFunctionAccess],                    
                           
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder],                    
       null        as [ScheduleGroup!2!Visible],                    
       null as [ScheduleGroup!2!CanChangeDisplayOrder],                    
                           
       null        as [Row!3!RowID],                    
       null        as [Row!3!BaseScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleCode],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleName],                    
       null        as [Row!3!DisplayOrder],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsMandatory],                    
       null         as [Row!3!InUse],                    
       null         as [Row!3!IsTracked],                    
       null        as [Row!3!Status],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ScheduleGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!CanChangeGroup],                    
       null        as [Row!3!ReadOnly],                       
                           
       null        as [ApplicableGroups!10],                    
       GroupCode       as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupCode],                    
       GroupName       as [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                    
       DisplayOrder      as [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder]              
       FROM                     
      @TempScheduleGroups                    
         
                         
                         
     ORDER BY [ApplicableGroup!11!DisplayOrder], [ApplicableGroup!11!GroupName],                     
        [ScheduleGroup!2!DisplayOrder], [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupCode], [ScheduleGroup!2!GroupName],                     
        [Row!3!ScheduleGroup], [Row!3!DisplayOrder], [Row!3!ScheduleName]
```

[image]

Comment: I am inserting it into #temp table and then assigning a parameter to it and then using for xml explicit.
select @xml = (select * from #temp for xml explicit)

Comment: Clearly the join `from dbo.tbl_MenuGroup m INNER JOIN @TempScheduleGroups tsg ON m.GroupCode = tsg.GroupCode where m.COAID = @COAID` returns no results. Sample data and expected results would help us immensely. You probably don't need `EXPLICIT`, using `PATH` or `AUTO` is usually easier. You certainly don't need a temp table.

Comment: Oh man, xml explicit, i haven't seen this since working on EDI stuff back in '07. You might save you a lot of pain if you convert to XML PATH

Comment: @Charlieface - have added the image of the output, is it that the first row where Parent is NULL is not always coming as the first row hence it gives the error?

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data, please only paste text. We need sample data for all tables in the query, as well as expected results (ie the XML you want) for that sample. The table you show isn't useful, it just represents the intermediate results of your `union all` query.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface i fixed the issue by adding an identity column with PK in temp table. so not getting the error anymore

Comment: @omkar, Post your solution as answer!